# How do I write a design rationale presentation for my client?

Tags: design, user-centered-design, client, presentation

I am currently working on a project and have been asked to submit a design rationale report that provides a coherent overview of the prototype design and reasons for choosing that design.

I'm looking for some examples where this has been communicated to clients before, as I'm quite new to the field.

Specifically, I'm looking for ideas around:

- Development of the prototype - what tool and why
- Clarifying the intended specification - how does the interaction unfold in relation to desired behaviour expected from the prototype. Also, if the prototype cannot do this due to trade-offs with budget, how could this be illustrated and communicated because user-research findings led to this?
- Examples of feedback sessions using the prototype, what expecting, guesses etc.

Comment: Who's the audience here? Is this upper management? External client?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Sounds like you're over thinking it.

Your client wants validation before implementing the design. You simply need to document your theories and findings in a way a general audience can understand. The formatting options for that presentation are a matter of preference and style. This kind of communication is one of the tricky, ancillary skills every successful UXer must develop.

### Just make sure you hit some high points:

- The problem(s) you're solving.
- The persona(s) you're targeting.
- The user flows you've designed (detail here really depends your audience).
- Some specific views or utilities that will make the most impact.
- Your test audience.
- What you learned or confirmed from testing.
- Some KPIs to track success post-launch.*

### Keep things light

You don't want to bore them, but you do want them to feel confident in the work behind your solution. Having deeper info in an appendix or ready in your back pocket allows you to drill down a little without cluttering the main storyline.

* Check out [the HEART framework](http://www.gv.com/lib/how-to-choose-the-right-ux-metrics-for-your-product) if you're not sure about the KPIs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are asking here.

What is your rationale for your particular design?- a summary of the research you built your design from should do the trick.

What is your rationale for going through a prototyping process rather than jumping straight to the finished product- it's quicker and cheaper, allows mistakes to be ironed out easily and without the users getting involved, makes for smoother change management/makes sure everyone is on the same page before launch, etc....